# PowerShell fails to call a simple function from an ASP.NET DLL

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm trying to call this really simple .NET 4 function with [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) v2. Its definition look like:

> Public Shared Function
>   currentSchoolYear() As String
>        Member of NM4.SiteAdmin.Logic.Subscription

Let's add the path to the DLL file containing that function. It's an [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) web application DLL file.

> PS > Add-Type -Path C:\xxx\bin\xxxWebApp.dll

Let's try it (FAIL!):

> PS > 
>   [NM4.SiteAdmin.Logic.Subscription]::currentSchoolYear() 
>   Exception calling "currentSchoolYear" 
>   with "0" argument(s): "The type 
>   initializer for 
>   'NM4.SiteAdmin.Logic.Subscription' 
>   threw an exception." At line:1 char:54 
>   + [NM4.SiteAdmin.Logic.Subscription]::currentSchoolYear 
>   <<<< () 
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], 
>   MethodInvocationException 
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Let's observe the class from PowerShell:

> PS > 
>   [NM4.SiteAdmin.Logic.Subscription] 
>   
>   IsPublic IsSerial Name 
>   BaseType 
>   
>   -------- -------- ---- --------  True     False    Subscription 
>   System.Object

Let's observe the function from PowerShell

> PS > 
>   [NM4.SiteAdmin.Logic.Subscription]::currentSchoolYear 
>   
>   
>   MemberType          : Method 
>   OverloadDefinitions : {static string 
>   currentSchoolYear()} TypeNameOfValue 
>   : 
>   System.Management.Automation.PSMethod 
>   Value               : static string 
>   currentSchoolYear() Name 
>   : currentSchoolYear IsInstance 
>   : True

Why oh why? It seems like the doc to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this command to get more details about the error:

> $error | Format-List -force

Which then throwed this more precise example:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object 
>   reference not set to an instance of an 
>   object. 
>                              at  
> NM4.SiteAdmin.GlobalFunctions.EstMachineProduction() 
>   in 
>   C:\xxx\Old_App_Code\DataModel\GlobalFunctions.vb:line 
>   17

And I discovered it was a call to the web.config that failed:

> Return 
>   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item("test_DBNM4").ConnectionString

DLL files loaded by PowerShell are probably not in their usual web context. I hardcoded a ConnectionString to test it (temporary, not a good security practice), and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an exception in the static constructor *OR* a type on which NM4.SiteAdmin.Logic.Subscription depends could not be loaded. I'm assuming "C:\xxx\bin\xxxWebApp.dll" and friends aren't in GAC and you're not running from "C:\xxx\bin\" so therefore powershell can't resolve the dependencies. Try running this from "C:\xxx\bin\".